# C Why does 3 divided by two equal 0 in one int, but 1 in another?

Tags: c, int, division

In C, I wrote a program that searches for a number in an ordered array using binary search.  I have the following code in one part of the program used to define two variables, middle and check.

(n is the size of the array)

```
int middle = 0;
int check = 0; //Checks if array holds an odd or even amount of numbers
check = n/2;
printf("check = %d\n", check);
```

For some reason, check was displayed as 0, and not as one.  What confused me even more, though, was that middle equaled one after I assigned n/2 to it as well.

```
    //Is there an even amount of numbers?
    printf("n = %d\n', n);
    printf("Checking if array is even or odd.\n');
    printf('Check starts out equaling %d after being divided\n", check);
    while (check > 1)
    {
        check = check/2;
        printf("Check equals %d\n", check);
    }
    if (check == 0)
    {
        //Number is even
        middle = n/2;
        printf("Even amount, middle = %d\n", middle);
    }
    else
    {
        //Number is odd
        middle = (n - 1)/2;
        printf("Odd amount, middle = %d\n", middle);
    }
```

When I run the code, using an array consisting of the numbers 2, 3, and 4, I get the following results.

```
check = 0
Even amount, middle equals 1
```

Why does check equal zero and middle equal one when both are ints and equal the same formula?  I would like both to equal one, but can not understand why check equals zero.

Comment: Use `check%2` to determine whether `check` is odd or even

Comment: You've described an impossible situation and illustrated it with incomplete code fragments. Post a complete, runnable program that demonstrates the anomaly. The proper result is that `3 / 2 == 1`.

Comment: when i executed your code with int n=3; I got results as "check = 1
Odd amount, middle = 1" . Strange  the answer is wrong to you

Comment: I added more code so I hope it is more understandable and relevant, I also included the result I wanted.  My apologies for being off-topic!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like the order you're executing the code may be a factor here. My guess is what's happening is that n = 0 when your first block of code is being run, while n actually equals what you're expecting it to be when the second block of code is running. It's difficult to tell without seeing the code in between the two blocks you posted, but check what the value of n is throughout your code and see if that's the case.

P.S.: you may want to throw a line break at the end of your "Even amount" printf.